# Name tuple variables in Scala

Tags: scala, tuples

Right now I have a `def` that returns a Tuple2[String, Int], or (String, Int).

```
def makeTuple(name: String, age: Int) : (String, Int) = {
  (name, age)
}
val nameAge = makeTuple("test", 12)
println(nameAge._1) // prints test
println(nameAge._2) // prints 12
```

**Ok this works, but Is there a way to give this tuple names?**

For example:

```
println(nameAge.name)
println(nameage.age)
```

Comment: You can destructure on the LHS of the val definition: `val (name, age) = makeTuple("test", 12)`. Otherwise, if you want named accessors, define a custom case class.

Comment: @jubobs Thanks! It works. Add it to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **jubobs** mentioned we can do it like this:

Using the case class:

```
 case class NameAge(name:(String), age:(Int))

  def makeTuple(name: String, age:Int): NameAge = {
    NameAge(name, age)
  }

  val nameAge = makeTuple("test",12)
  println(nameAge.name, nameAge.age)
```

Using val:

```
  def makeTuple1(name: String, age:Int): (String, Int) = {
    (name, age)
  }

  val (name, age) = makeTuple1("test", 12)
  println(name, age)
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that case classes can be defined locally, so they don't pollute the namespace and can be close to where you use them:

```
def f() = {
  ...
  case class NameAge(name: String, age: Int)
  val nameAge = NameAge("test", 12)
  println(nameAge.name)
  println(nameAge.age)
  ...
}
```

Alternately, you could use a library like [Scala Records](https://github.com/scala-records/scala-records):

```
val nameAge = Rec("name" -> "test", "age" -> 12)
println(nameAge.name)
println(nameAge.age)
```

Comment: I'd never heard of Scala Records before. This is pretty nifty.

Answer (score 3):

You can just assign both names to the output of your function:

```
val (name, age) = makeTuple("test", 12)
```

Or even get rid of the function

```
val (name, age) = ("test", 12)
```

Then (in both cases) you can perform your prints as follows:

```
println(name)
println(age)
```